# Normalisation in linear regression - all vs. just 1 variable

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, normalization

I have three independent, numerical variables in my linear regression. All of them have different scales. My professor now suggested to use a z-score normalisation for one of them (sentiment magnitude, variable 3 in the list below) to make them comparable. Shouldn't I normalise all of them to really make them comparable?

The variables are:
1) Project description length (word count) - ranges from 10 to 1000 words
2) Description's sentiment score - ranges from -1 to 1 (from negative to positive)
3) Description's sentiment magnitude - ranges from 0 to infinity

The dependent variable I am predicting is the days needed to receive funding for a project.

Also, I am wondering how to interpret the coefficients in the linear regression for the normalised variables? Does this make a difference when using other models (non-linear models such as random forest)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the language/tool you preferred? Check my answer which supports Python.

Answer (score -1):

Set all of your predictors to x and response to y and set normalize=True in your LinearRegression object as below.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd

regr = LinearRegression(normalize=True)  
regr.fit(x, y)
intercept = round(regr.intercept_, 2)
cols = x.columns.tolist()
coefficients = dict(zip(cols, [round(i, 4) for i in regr.coef_]))
```

Comment: Hi Surani, my question was not how to implement a linear regression but rather what effects a variable normalization would have on it, especially when normalizing only 1 variable out of the 3 independent ones

Comment: Normalization is dividing the indepenedent variable by Std deviation.The idea is to understand how the coefficient is impacted by std deviation, when all other variables are same.Like in your case you have 3 independent variables.You can see how the out come of your dependent variable is affected when each of these 3 variables are divided by the standard deviation, keeping the other 2 as fixed.

Comment: To answer your 2nd question , on choosing the a non linear model , depends on the data that you have for these variables.if it requires too much of overfitting  in the curve , then you can think of using random forest.